# Creating a new String from a Charset throws NoSuchMethodError (Android)

Tags: java, android, string, character-encoding

I have a snippet of code creating a new `String` as follow:

```
private final static Charset UNICODE_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

public String makeNewUnicodeString(byte[] octects) {
    return new String(octects, UNICODE_CHARSET);
}
```

It works fine when testing on my computer. But when I run it on Android emulator, it throws:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.<init>
```

But this works:

```
public String makeUnicodeString(byte[] octets) {
    try {
        return new String(octets, "UTF-8")
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
       // never throw.
    }
}
```

I'm using Android 2.2 API 8, rev 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the constructor `String (byte[] data, Charset charset)` was only added in API Level 9 (Android SDK 2.3). So updating SDK version solved my problems. Thanks everyone.

Here the reference:

[String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) - Android Developer Reference.

[API Levels of Android Platform](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#level9).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a difference between Java 5 and Java 6.

The constructor that accepts CharSet is only in Java 6 and not in Java 5.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

EDIT -- The constructor in question is in the android api .. this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: The Android SDK offers the constructor though, [`String(byte array,Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
byte[] raw = null;
        try {
            raw = key.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```